# Write dataframe as csv to S3 with kms encrypted keys without providing key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, amazon-kms

I have created CSV files through spark dataframe which are getting KMS encrypted automatically.

For your reference, I am giving a sample code snippet that is creating these KMS encrypted files. If you see while writing I am not giving any KMS key. It will be really helpful if you tell the root cause.

```
val df=spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("s3:///test/App_IP.csv")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("test")
val df1=spark.sql("select name from test")
df1.coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("s3://test/city5/")
```

This code I am executing from spark-shell in EMR cluster (emr-5.24.0), spark version is Spark 2.4.2

Answer (score 1):

You can use S3 Encryption as described in the EMR docs [Amazon S3 Server-Side Encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-emrfs-encryption.html#emr-emrfs-encryption-sse):

> `fs.s3.enableServerSideEncryption`: When set to true, objects stored in Amazon S3 are encrypted using server-side encryption. If no key is specified, SSE-S3 is used.
> `fs.s3.serverSideEncryption.kms.keyId`: Specifies an AWS KMS key ID or ARN. If a key is specified, SSE-KMS is used.

**Create a cluster with SSE-S3 enabled:**

```sh
aws emr create-cluster --release-label emr-5.24.0 \
--instance-count 3 --instance-type m5.xlarge --emrfs Encryption=ServerSide
```

**Create a cluster with SSE-KMS enabled:**

```sh
aws emr create-cluster --release-label emr-5.24.0 \ --instance-count 3 \
--instance-type m5.xlarge --use-default-roles \
--emrfs Encryption=ServerSide,Args=[fs.s3.serverSideEncryption.kms.keyId=<keyId>]
```

Or by providing a cluster configuration JSON :

```json
[
  ...
   {
    "Classification":"emrfs-site",
    "Properties": {
       "fs.s3.enableServerSideEncryption": "true",
       "fs.s3.serverSideEncryption.kms.keyId":"<keyId>"
    }
  }
]
```